# необходимо отключить фокус ввода при нажатии кнопки на React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

у меня текущая архитектура проекта
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при нажатии кнопки необходимо отключить фокусировку инпута

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
//надо вынести состояние в радител
export const Main = () => {
    const [focus,setFocus] = useState(true)
    const handleFocus = () => {
        setFocus(() => false)
    }
    //button вызывает внутри handleFocus
    <Button handleFocus={handleFocus}/>
    //input получает значения
    <Input focus={focus}/>
}
```

Comment: Input не имеет attr focus! место него есть метод blur(), но как поднят это в родител,

Comment: Mirjalol я вообше машинально ответил НО созрел вопрос как это у тебя после взоимодействия с другим элементом фокус вообше остается?

Comment: да и что за !!! :) какой атрибут это обычная переменная